# How do i check if someone has a specific role discord py

Tags: discord.py

I want to create a specific max bet amount for 5 roles, but I can't find how I can do it

```
async def bet(ctx, name, amount : int):
       if ctx.author.name.has_role("name") and amount>100:
            await ctx.send("You can't bet that much !")
```

But it returns:

`'str' object has no attribute 'has_role'`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do instead of comparing a role to the user's role is doing the opposite. I would compare a list of all the roles that the user has to another role.

---

This is how your function would look like in that way:

```
@client.command() # or commands.command() if in cog
async def bet(ctx, amount: int):
    roles_user_has = []

    # Here we turn the role values to strings for easier comparison.
    for role in ctx.author.roles:
        roles_user_has.append(str(role))
    
    # Check 2 conditions
    if "name" in roles_user_has and amount > 100:
        await ctx.send('you can\'t bet that much!')
```

---

Comment: Why is that? You're not saying *anything* that could make *anyone* improve...

Comment: `ctx.author.roles` is already a list. You're going through it with a for loop and appending to a new one, you can simply `roles_user_has = ctx.author.roles`. That's first, second of all you can simply use `has_role` or `has_any_role` decorators.

Comment: Didn't he just mention that `has_role` didn't work out for him? But I could agree that `ctx.author.roles` is a list. The reason why I looped through it was to turn values into strings so that they could be easier to compare.

Comment: He's not using it correctly, `string`  doesn't have the `has_role` method, it's `commands.has_role`.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the `has_any_role` decorator:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Some role name', 8716273861872) # You can use the role name and/or the role ID
async def bet(ctx, amount: int):
   ...
```

[reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_any_role#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role)

Answer (score -1):

`ctx.author.name` returns you a string, you need to use `ctx.author` to get `discord.Member` object. But `discord.Member` object also has no attribute `has_role`. You can use `discord.Member.roles`, it returns a list of member's roles. Then you can check if a specific role is in that list.

```py
async def bet(ctx, amount: int):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='role name')
    if role in ctx.author.roles and amount>100:
        await ctx.send("You can't bet that much !")
```